# Return column in php where column is not the same as column requested

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query:

```
function find_Friends($UserID){
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    if (!$mysqli) {
        die('There was a problem connecting to the database.');
    }
    $query="SELECT * FROM Friends WHERE UserID = '$UserID' OR FriendID = '$UserID'";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
    //List all relevant
    while($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
       //Do logic   
    }
    $mysqli->close();
}
```

So assuming the query is this:

```
SELECT * FROM Friends WHERE UserID = '123' OR FriendID = '123'
```

My query returns the following:

```
UserID | FriendID
123    |  456
```

The question I have is, how do I return FriendID 456 in php?
I basically only want to return the column that *isn't* the queried number, in this case 123.

So if instead I was looking for 8434 and I got a return of:

```
UserID | FriendID
2356   | 8434
```

I'd want to return UserID, rather than FriendID, but in the original query I'd want to return FriendID.

How would I do this in php/mysql?

Comment: Side comment: You're using mysqli, why don't you use parameterized queries?

Comment: You just have to make comparision in PHP with your initial value (as you have only 2 column, it is easy. `if ($row['UserID'] == $UserId) ....`

Comment: I've taught myself php and mysqli (having tried to make the transition from mysql). I'm not actually sure what a parameterized query is.

Comment: @DavidG Google "mysqli prepared statement", "parameterized query", and "SQL injection", and have a good read.

Comment: Ah, I would normally bind queries admittedly, to avoid SQL injection, but in this instance I was just testing and got stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only care about the number and not which column it is, you can change your query to this:

```
SELECT IF(UserID='123',FriendID,UserID) AS Number FROM Friends WHERE UserID = '123' OR FriendID = '123'
```

Or, if you do care about which one it is, then keep the query string as-is and apply this PHP:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
    if ($row['UserID'] == $UserID) {
        echo "Friend ID: " . $row['FriendID'];
    } else {
        echo "User ID: " . $row['UserID'];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for, thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

use this logic

```
while($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
   if($row['UserID'] == $UserID)
   {
        echo $row['FriendID'];
   } else {
        echo $row['UserID'];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just `UNION` both sides, making your query:

```
SELECT FriendId
FROM Friends
WHERE UserId = @UserId
UNION ALL
SELECT UserId AS FriendId
FROM Friends
WHERE FriendId = @UserId
```

This will return all friends of `@UserId` and all users who `@UserId` is a friend of, in one simple list.